# Cassandra keyspace creation goes in infinite loop with cassandra driver 2.2.0-rc3

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.2, cassandra-driver

I have setup a 3 nodes cassandra cluster in single machine(Ubantu), And I do the following -

1. All three nodes up and application is able to create keyspace.
2. Shutdown one  out of 3 running nodes and application is still able
   to create keyspace.
3. Shutdown one more node out of now 2 running
   nodes and start it immediately and now application is not able to
   create keyspace, it keeps on reporting (like infinite loop) about -

   2017-09-25 14:42:40 INFO  RequestHandler:561 - Query CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS 
   MYKEYSPACE WITH replication =  {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1':'2'};
   is not prepared on /127.0.0.1:9042, preparing before retrying executing. Seeing this
   message a few times is fine, but seeing it a lot may be source of performance 
   problems

My application log is flooded with these messages and it resulted java heap out error.

**Note- I have Replication factor as 2, and the version of cassandra using is 2.2.6 with cassandra driver is 2.2.0-rc3. When I revert back to cassandra driver 2.1.3 everything is working fine, so just wondering if some issues at driver level side**

Further more to add on this I debugged the code even at cassandra driver level and found this is because of the below given method of com.datastax.driver.core.Connection class -

```
  private void flush(FlushItem item) {
    EventLoop loop = item.channel.eventLoop();
    Flusher flusher = flusherLookup.get(loop);
    if (flusher == null) {
        Flusher alt = flusherLookup.putIfAbsent(loop, flusher = new Flusher(loop));
        if (alt != null)
            flusher = alt;
    }

    flusher.queued.add(item);
    flusher.start();
}
```

So after bringing back node online (2 nodes running now out of 3), the RequestHandler keeps on reporting about query not prepared, hence preparing before retry when this call is made -

```
public ResponseHandler write(ResponseCallback callback, boolean startTimeout)
{
 ....
 ....
 ....
flush(new FlushItem(channel, request, writeHandler(request, handler)));
 ....
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading cassandra driver version to 3.3.0, the issue did not get encountered. I believe some bugs are there in 2.2.0-rc3 which is release candidate version.